# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'. I have been trying to debug this error for 20 minutes

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

Nothing I do seems to work. I clicked like 10 links on the subject, and nothing worked to solve my issue. Sorry for the long code.

```
from tkinter import *


numbers = {}


root = Tk()

root.title("Calculator")


display_numbers = Entry(root, width=30)

display_numbers.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)


def clicked_number(value):
    print(value)
    display_numbers.insert(len(display_numbers.get()), value)


def clicked_clear():
    print("cleared")
    display_numbers.delete(0, END)


def clicked_add():
    print("added")
    display_numbers.delete(0, END)
    number = display_numbers.get()
    numbers[len(numbers)] = number


def clicked_equals():
    summed = 0
    for number in numbers:
        summed += str(numbers.get(number))
    display_numbers.delete(0, END)
    display_numbers.insert(0, summed)


button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=30, command=lambda: clicked_number(1))
button_2 = Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=30, command=lambda: clicked_number(2))
button_3 = Button(root, text="3", padx=40, pady=30, command=lambda: clicked_number(3))

button_4 = Button(root, text="4", padx=40, pady=30, command=lambda: clicked_number(4))
button_5 = Button(root, text="5", padx=40, pady=30, command=lambda: clicked_number(5))
button_6 = Button(root, text="6", padx=40, pady=30, command=lambda: clicked_number(6))

button_7 = Button(root, text="7", padx=40, pady=30, command=lambda: clicked_number(7))
button_8 = Button(root, text="8", padx=40, pady=30, command=lambda: clicked_number(8))
button_9 = Button(root, text="9", padx=40, pady=30, command=lambda: clicked_number(9))

button_0 = Button(root, text="0", padx=40, pady=30, command=lambda: clicked_number(0))
button_clear = Button(root, text="Clear", padx=80, pady=30, command=clicked_clear)

button_add = Button(root, text="+", padx=40, pady=30, command=clicked_add)
button_equals = Button(root, text="=", padx=40, pady=30, command=clicked_equals)


button_7.grid(column=0, row=1)
button_8.grid(column=1, row=1)
button_9.grid(column=2, row=1)

button_4.grid(column=0, row=2)
button_5.grid(column=1, row=2)
button_6.grid(column=2, row=2)

button_1.grid(column=0, row=3)
button_2.grid(column=1, row=3)
button_3.grid(column=2, row=3)

button_0.grid(column=0, row=4)
button_clear.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=2)

button_add.grid(column=0, row=5)
button_equals.grid(column=1, row=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Here is the entire error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\itsuw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/itsuw/PycharmProjects/tkintercalc/main.py", line 37, in clicked_equals
    summed += str(numbers.get(number))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: from the error message it is clear you passed an incorrect value; check everywhere you passed a int value or string value to make sure thats what is meant to be passed

Answer (score 1):

```
summed = 0
for number in numbers:
    summed += str(numbers.get(number))
```

You explicitly initialize `summed` to an `int`. Then you try to add explicitly cast `str`s to it. You either need to start with `''` (or some other `str`) and concatenate `str`s, or start with `0` (or some other `int`) and add `int`s, choose one.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting numbers.get(number) to a string then using += on an int.

change `summed += str(numbers.get(number))` to `summed += numbers.get(number)`